# SOAPUI Certificate authentication

Tags: web-services, authentication, encryption, certificate, soapui

I am trying to hit a remote web service and check if the service is working. To hit the service I am using SOAPUI client. The first time I tried, I got a 403/Forbidden response. The team developing the remote service provided me with a digital certificate to use to making the request. 
How should I use this certificate for making the request. I am a fairly new to the concept of using digital certificates in web service authentication as well as to soap ui.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to configure soapui for client certificate authentication.

There are a number of ways to do this.

1. You can add an authentication option under the connection details for the project.
2. You can configure the certificates for the request under the ws-auth tab

Have a look at the link below.  It gives some basic setup steps to assist with soapui
<strike>[SoapUI Configure Client certificate authentication (soapui 3.6)](http://geekswithblogs.net/gvdmaaden/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-configure-soapui-with-client-certificate-authentication.aspx)</strike>
[SoapUI Sending requests](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/sending-https-requests/)

Comment: In newer versions of SoapUI (i.e. 5.4) you can import your client certificate in a local keystore then > Preferences > SSL Settings > Keystore - Keystore Password

Comment: I needed to run SoapUI as administrator to get access to the certificate. After doing this once this was not required any more.

Comment: @sweetfa Dead link.

Comment: Good link. I missed choosing the local keystore in the request, the first time.