# unable to hit the webservice using soapUI after proxy setting

Tags: java, proxy, apache-axis, soapui, webservices-client

Due to change in server configuration, in my project. We apt to proxy server while calling the webservice which is axis2. But the problem, here is we cannot able to access the the endpoint through the soapui(After configuring the proxy configuration in the preference->proxy setting) but i can access the endpoint through eclipse code after configuring the proxy. Here is the exception i am getting in the soapUI logs

```
Fri Mar 21 19:09:51 IST 2014:ERROR:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest cannot be cast to org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest cannot be cast to org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HeadderRequestInterceptor.process(HeadderRequestInterceptor.java:42)
at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:108)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:174)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpClientSupport.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.createTunnelToTarget(DefaultRequestDirector.java:830)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:739)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:565)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:236)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:345)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:241)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you add your error log? Also, what version of soapUI are you using? and do you also have a certificate? there seems to be a bug about this issue..check http://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/636/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am using soapUI 4.5.1 and i updated the question for the error log. Sorry i didnt understand about certificate. can you please elaborate about it...

Comment: I meant to ask if the service uses SSL.

Comment: yes it uses certificate but earilier without proxy i am able to executed without certificate...

Comment: Earlier there was no authentication and probably no certificate that is why you were able to access the service without any problem. Now that you have authentication and certification, you'll need to configure soapUI accordingly. Check out http://geekswithblogs.net/gvdmaaden/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-configure-soapui-with-client-certificate-authentication.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994164/soapui-certificate-authentication

Comment: Thanks very much for your responseI add the jks client certificate  in ssl settings of soap ui but still i am getting same error...

Comment: Still the same error? Well there is still an open bug out there see link in my first comment.

Comment: try restarting soapUI!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using SoapUI 4.5.1 and facing the same exception.  I almost spend my entire day in dubgging it and later on I downloaded SoapUI 5.0.0 and tested same webservice and that works.

By reading http://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/636/ this URL I found that it was a bug in SoapUI 4.5.1 version.

So better always use the new verions of tool if they are available :)

Comment: It was problem in my network that is not allowing that proxy. but now the issue got resolved by allowing the proxy in the network. Thanks for the help Anupam